# Artifactory: upload with api key (not password)

Tags: artifactory

How would you upload an artifact to artifactory without using a password?

If I create a new user specific for uploads, that user by default doesn't git the 'upload' permission unless they are an administrator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To upload with credentials

```
curl -u admin:'correct-horse-battery-staple' -T foo.zip
```

To upload with an api key

```
curl --header 'X-JFrog-Art-Api: 1234567890' -T foo.zip
```

Alternativly you can use the syntax `<username:apikey>`

```
curl -u admin:1234567890 -T foo.zip
```

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

You can create the api key on the user profile page.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

See the various authentication options, including authentication using API key, in the JFrog CLI for Artifactory documentation page:
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `.pypirc` you can just put:

```
[distutils]
index-servers = local

[local]
repository:  https://artifactory-url/repo
username: <username>
password: <api-key>
```

Then you can upload using `python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r local`.

Though my user is an admin at the moment so it answers only the API key part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking at a nuget artifact, here's the one line CLI command below.

```
nuget push <your-package-name.nupkg> -source <artifactory-repo-url>/nuget-local/ -ApiKey <your-user-name>:<apikey>
```

It's buried in the [jfrog documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/NuGet+Repositories). I would think uploading other artifacts would follow a similar pattern.